# CakePHP 1.3 HABTM - Add works fine, Edit will not save HABTMs

Tags: cakephp, save, edit, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am having a problem with my HABTM updates in CakePHP 1.3.

First off, here is the relationship declaration as it appears in the Alert model:

```
var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Region' => array(
        'className' => 'Region',
        'joinTable' => 'alerts_regions',
        'foreignKey' => 'alert_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'region_id',
        'unique' => true,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'deleteQuery' => '',
        'insertQuery' => ''
    ),
    'ForecastZone' => array(
        'className' => 'ForecastZone',
        'joinTable' => 'alerts_forecast_zones',
        'foreignKey' => 'alert_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'forecast_zone_id',
        'unique' => true,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'deleteQuery' => '',
        'insertQuery' => ''
    )       
);
```

When I submit my form to create a record for the model everything works fine and the associated models (HABTM tables) get the proper records created. $this->data looks like this:

```
Array
(
[Alert] => Array
    (
        [title] => Test Alert
        [overview] => This is a test alert overview
        [user_id] => 3
        [timeframe] => Tonight
        [effective] => 2012-07-05 18:00:00
        [effective_time] => 6:00
        [effective_ampm] => pm
        [expires] => 2012-07-05 21:00:00
        [expires_time] => 9:00
        [expires_ampm] => pm
    )

[Region] => Array
    (
        [Region] => Array
            (
                [0] => 6
                [1] => 5
            )

    )

[ForecastZone] => Array
    (
        [ForecastZone] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1598
                [1] => 1594
                [2] => 2685
                [3] => 1565
                [4] => 1613
                [5] => 1595
            )

    )

)
```

Now, because of the complex associations with this Model (Alert, ForecastZone, and Region) I have it set up so there is a separate interface on the Alerts/Edit page to update JUST the forecast zones. The Alerts controller figures out what Regions the Forecast Zones belong to, and the controller populates the [Region][Region] value on it's own. The ForecastZones are selected from an interface where the user clicks to select which zones they want.

When I submit a form to the /alerts/edit action, I can save the Alert data (title, overview, etc) no problem. However, it is IMPOSSIBLE for me to get the related HABTM models to update. I am at the verge of just doing it all with $this->query() but I am going to try one last time to figure out what is going wrong.

Here is what the form looks like when I submit to /alerts/edit:

```
Array
(
    [Alert] => Array
        (
            [id] => 37
            [fcz_update] => true
        )

    [Region] => Array
        (
            [Region] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 6
                    [1] => 5
                )

        )

    [ForecastZone] => Array
        (
            [ForecastZone] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1595
                    [1] => 1613
                    [2] => 1565
                    [3] => 2685
                    [4] => 1594
                    [5] => 1598
                    [6] => 2989
                    [7] => 3723
                    [8] => 1650
                    [9] => 1626
                    [10] => 1653
                    [11] => 1678
                    [12] => 3447
                    [13] => 1649
                    [14] => 1654
                    [15] => 1675
                    [16] => 3448
                    [17] => 1668
                    [18] => 1664
                    [19] => 1635
                    [20] => 1667
                    [21] => 1628
                )

        )

)
```

I have tried $this->Alert->save($this->data) as well as $this->Alert->saveAll($this->data) and neither of these work. Both save() functions return a 1 (true) so I assume they are successful... yet when I return to my recently edited records... nothing has changed. I tried adding all of the other Alert data into the form as hidden fields, so I could save the whole alert data at once... this does not work either.

Edit:

Here is the code from my alerts_controller.php edit function/action that performs the save operations:

```
if (!empty($this->data)) {

    //If we are updating forecast zones
    if(array_key_exists('fcz_update',$this->data['Alert'])){ 

        $fcz_str = $this->data['Alert']['AlertForecastZone'];
        $forecast_zones = explode(',',$fcz_str);

        $fcz_regions = $this->ForecastZone->query('SELECT DISTINCT region_id FROM forecast_zones WHERE id IN (' . $fcz_str . ') AND region_id != 0;');


        if(!empty($fcz_regions)){

            foreach($fcz_regions as $fczr){ $alert_regions[] = $fczr['forecast_zones']['region_id']; }
            $this->data['Region']['Region'] = $alert_regions;   

        }


        $this->data['ForecastZone']['ForecastZone'] = $forecast_zones;
        unset($this->data['Alert']['AlertForecastZone']);               

        //debug($this->data);

        $this->Alert->save($this->data);

        //Go back to alert edit to review changes
        $this->redirect($this->referer());              

    } 

}
```

The best bugs are the ones that throw no errors or have any way for you to figure out what's going wrong. So angry and frustrated... please help.

Comment: We'll need your controller action :)

Comment: I just added what you mentioned. I don't have the entire controller in there, but the relevant parts in the beginning of the edit() action that performs the save.

Comment: You will have to manipulate your posted data array while passing it to saveAll() method with 'deep' opion.

Answer (score 0):

Play with the keying of your data.

Try [ForecastZone][0] => 1595
or
[ForecastZone][0][id] => 1595
or even
[ForecastZone][0][ForecastZone] => 1595

I always got to fight to remember what the correct keying order is for the HABTM

Answer (score 0):

To save associated and related data you need to use the `saveAll` function    `$this->Alert->saveAll($this->data)`